# How to compare dates for conditional formatting?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to create conditional style  for JasperReport's report and I need to compare date with current date if not null or blank. I have tried with several ways but no luck till now. Please suggest what is wrong in below condition.

```
(($F{ORDER_BY_DATE} != " ") && ($F{ORDER_BY_DATE} != null)) ?
    ((new Date().after(new Date($F{ORDER_BY_DATE}))) ? true : false) :
 false
```

I'm using iReport 5.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested it, but I would change your code just by seeing it to this:

```
$F{ORDER_BY_DATE} != null && !$F{ORDER_BY_DATE}.trim().isEmpty() && new Date().after(new Date($F{ORDER_BY_DATE}))
```

- `trim()` removes all spaces at the begin & end of the string
- `isEmpty()` is equal to `.length == 0`

Maybe this solves your problem

Comment: My report is now getting compiled and running fine now but data is not getting displayed from the column on which above conditional style is applied. Any guess why ??

Comment: It sounds like that the statement of the conditional style is true and your style is used, but the style itself contains a configuration which causes that the data isn't displayed. But that's another topic/question

Comment: Yes. I have corrected my style attributes and now it's working fine. Thanks